# Square root of unitary matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, radicals, matrix-calculus, unitary-matrices

It is known fact that if $U$ unitary matrix in $M_n(C)$ (i.e. $UU^*=U^*U=I$) then $U$ has square root $V$ which is also unitary matrix. But suppose that $U$ unitary matrix and $V\in M_n(C)$ such that $U=V^2$. Then is it true that the $V$ is also unitary matrix?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, e.g. with 
$$V=\pmatrix{1&1\\0&-1}$$
we have $V^2=I$ which is unitary but $V$ is not.