# If matrix $A$ is unitary and $B^2=A$, is $B$ necessarily unitary?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If matrix $A$ is unitary and the matrix $B$ satisfies $B^2=A$, is $B$ necessarily unitary?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "define the following statement". Do you mean to ask: "Suppose $A$ is unitary and $B$ satisfies $B^2=A$. Is $B$ necessarily unitary?"

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Hint: take $A$ to be the identity matrix.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2717389/square-root-of-unitary-matrix?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Let $A\in U_n$.

$\textbf{Proposition}$: Case 1. $A$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues. Then $A$ admits $2^n$ square roots and each of them is unitary.

Case 2. $A$ admits at least one multiple eigenvalue. Then $A$ admits an infinity of square roots that are not unitary and an infinity of square roots that are unitary.