# If matrix $A$ is unitary and $B^2 = A$ then $B$ is also unitary

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonal-matrices

I need to prove or give a counterexample:

> If matrix $A$ is unitary and $B^2 = A$ then $B$ is also unitary

I think the statement is true since the unitary matrix A can only be Identity matrix I or negative identity matrix $-I$; and $B=A^2$ is an identity matrix which makes sure it is unitary.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3163142/if-matrix-a-is-unitary-and-b2-a-is-b-necessarily-unitary

Comment: "Unitary matrix can only be identity or negative identity" : *False*, even in the one dimensional case!

Comment: Asking the same question twice is a violation of the rules of this site. I suggest you delete this question before the mods do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

You are incorrect. Both $I$ and $-I$ are, of course, unitary, but there are many such matrices, e.g.
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{2}/2 & -\sqrt{2}/2 \\ \sqrt{2}/2 & \sqrt{2}/2 \end{bmatrix}
$$

But think: matrix $M$ is unitary if and only if $M^T M = I$. What could you say above $(M^2)^T (M^2)$ in such circumstances?

Your question asks to go the other way. If $M^TM = I$ and $A^2 = M$, can we say that $A^TA = I$ as well?

Comment: I think the question is not "if $A$ is unitary then $A^2$ is", but rather, "if $A$ is unitary, then any square root of $A$ is".

Comment: Ok, i think i got it , since in this case (M^2)^T(M^2) will also equal to the Identity matrix, which proves that the statement is true.

Comment: @DennyShen the other comment got it right. You want to go the other way. Say $M^TM = I$, and $A^2 = M$. Can you then say $A^T A = I$ as well?