If $||S^{-1} v|| = ||Sv||$ for all $v$, then $S$ is a unitary operator
The following question comes from Axler's book on linear algebra: section 7D, problem 12 of the fourth edition. (Not sure if it matters, but we are assuming that our vector space is finite-dimensional.)
Prove or give a counterexample: if $S \in \mathcal{L} (V)$ is invertible and  $||S^{-1} v|| = ||Sv||$ for all $v$, then $S$ is a unitary operator.
I'm not sure if this is true, but I tried to show that $S^{-1} = S^*$ (which would imply $S$ is unitary) by showing that:
$$\langle S^{-1}v - S^* v,  S^{-1}v - S^* v\rangle = 0$$
But I can't see how to show this. A small hint about how to approach either proving this or finding a counterexample would be much appreciated!

Which exercise is that (that is, what's its number)?

Sorry, will edit the post; but the exercise is section 7D, problem 12, of the fourth edition of Linear Algebra Done Right.

Here's an easy example: Consider the matrix
$$S = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$$
as a linear map on $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the usual inner product (i.e. dot product). Notice that $S^2$ is the identity.
Claim: We have that $\|Sv\| = \|S^{-1}v\|$ for all $v$.
Proof: Fix $v$ and let $w = S^{-1}v$. Then $\|Sv\| = \|S^2w\| = \|w\| = \|S^{-1}v\|$. $\blacksquare$
Claim: $S$ is not unitary.
Sketch of Proof: Check that
$$S^* = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix} \text{ and } S^{-1} =  \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}.$$
Finish by using the fact that $S$ is unitary if and only if $S^* = S^{-1}$.

Final remarks: The assumption shows that $S^2$ is unitary, but not necessarily that $S$ is unitary. So we're just using https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2717389/square-root-of-unitary-matrix

Really nice example, thank you so much!!
